# What is an appropriate post hoc test after the Friedman test?

Tags: paired-data, post-hoc, friedman-test

I've read several posts related to this, but I'm not sure.
so I'm posting the question in case it's redundant.

I have been conducting an experiment using a **within-subject design, comparing three conditions**. The collected data is **continuous** and ranges from 0 to 240 (approximately).
(I used a simulator sickness questionnaire; SSQ)

After performing a normality test, I found that the data does not follow a normal distribution. Consequently, I decided to use the Friedman test for statistical analysis.

However, I am now faced with a question regarding the appropriate method for conducting pairwise comparisons. In the past, I have used the Wilcoxon signed-rank test and applied Bonferroni correction.

Recently, I came across the Durbin-Conover test in Jamovi software, which compares ranks instead of scores/means(?) like the Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

I am considering using the Durbin-Conover test for post hoc analysis after the Friedman test.
Yet, I wonder why we use the Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Am I misunderstanding something?

Finally, in my experiment, can I use the Durbin-Conover method for pair-wise comparison?